# front controller of my module doesn't work neither shows any changes or validates order in prestashop1.7

Tags: prestashop

I'm implementing external payment gateway. But Front controller does not show any changes in the frontoffice. Atleast it should throw some error(so it would be easy to understand) but instead it shows no changes.
I have tried deleting, again creating same file but i think there is something wrong with the code.

I'm a newbie in custom module development. Hopefully anybody can point me in right direction. A quick help would be really appreciated.
Please check my code below. Correct me if i missed something.

```
<?php

require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/config/config.inc.php';

require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/latpayredirect.php';

class LatpayRedirectValidationModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController

{

    
    public $warning = '';

    public $message = '';

    public function initContent()

    {  

      parent::initContent();



      $this->context->smarty->assign(array(

          'warning' => $this->warning,

          'message' => $this->message

          ));        

     

      $this->setTemplate('module:latpayredirect/views/templates/front/payment_return.tpl');    

    }
  

    public function postProcess()

    {

      ob_start();

    $context = Context::getContext();



    if (is_null($context->cart)) {

      $context->cart = new Cart($context->cookie->id_cart);

  }

  if (is_null($context->cart->id_currency)) {

      $context->cart->id_currency = $context->cookie->id_currency;

  }

      $cart = $this->context->cart;

      $this->abrir("http://davivienda.com");


       if ($cart->id_customer == 0 || $cart->id_address_delivery == 0 || $cart->id_address_invoice == 0 || !$this->module->active) {

           Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order&step=1');

       }

       $customer = new Customer($cart->id_customer);

       if (!Validate::isLoadedObject($customer)) {

           Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order&step=1');

       }

      // $currency = $this->context->currency;

      $currency = $cart->id_currency;

       $total = (float)$cart->getOrderTotal(true, Cart::BOTH);

       $object = new filemain();

       $order = $object->methodCreateInMain($cart->id, Configuration::get('PS_OS_PAYMENT'), $total, $currency, $customer->secure_key);

       //The order passes directly on paid status

       $this->module->validateOrder((int)$cart->id, Configuration::get('PS_OS_PAYMENT'), $total, $this->module->displayName, null, array(), (int)$currency->id, false, $customer->secure_key);

       Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order-confirmation&id_cart='.(int)$cart->id.'&id_module='.(int)$this->module->id.'&id_order='.$this->module->currentOrder.'&key='.$customer->secure_key);

   }

   public function abrir($param)

   {

       echo" <script> window.open(URL,'ventana1,'width=300,height=300,scrollbars=NO')</script> ";

   }  

}
```

Comment: hi there. please help if possible. I'm in desperate need of help.

Comment: whats your module name? and your php file name?

are you getting 404 error page?

Comment: Module name: latpayredirect,
  php file: latpayredirect.php
No i'm not getting any error page. The payment page takes the input data of .tpl file. But controller doesn't work which would have validated my order.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a simple module as yours and the controller works fine. Please find the below code.

I think, something wrong with your class name & file name (try file name in lowercases, and controller class name should be like class )

/modules/latpayredirect/latpayredirect.php

```
<?php

class Latpayredirect extends PaymentModule
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'latpayredirect';
        $this->author = 'abdullacm';
        $this->version = '1.0.0';
        $this->need_instance = 0;

        parent::__construct();
        $this->displayName = 'payment module';
        $this->description = 'payment module';
    }
}
```

/modules/latpayredirect/controllers/front/validation.php

```
<?php

class LatpayredirectValidationModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{
    public function initContent()
    {
        echo 'from latpay validation front controller';
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried as you suggested but nothing changes. Still same

Comment: your controller works, but order is not creating, thats you are facing ?

Comment: no no sir. Controller doesn't work. For checking I even deleted 'public function initContent()' in controller to see if it throws some fatal error but it didnt show anything at all. That's how i came to know that controller doesn't work.

Comment: please share your module as zip, i can try at my side

Comment: you can check here. Its the same module. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71826472/the-payment-screen-total-value-does-not-matches-with-the-total-order-amount-in-c


Also can you help me with how to generate transaction key like sha1, set POST params for request url and validate them? Please add in the code if possible.

Comment: let me check the module

Comment: Please let me know if you have any update. I'm eagerly waiting for your response.

Comment: sorry, was busy, can you please share the module as zip? seems you have multiple tpl files in the module but you have shared 1

Comment: how to upload zip here?

Comment: make a zip and share via google drive or alternatives

Comment: here . https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eZvmcw9niKevrVWK7m1EhhVugWqm4EQs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: what about payment gateway details?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it appears that you cannot override controllers or classes from a module with the method you are using (even though they say it works in the documentation!).

The way that worked for me is to copy your  override class (for instance here the override of the Order class) **directly** in the main file of the module:

```php
<?php
    class MyModule extends Module 
    {
    
    }
    
    class MyCustomOrder extends Order
    {
    
    }
?>
```

Good luck!